# How to convert a python script in a local conda env into systemd service in Linux?

Tags: python, conda, systemd

I have a daemon `Python` script in my `conda` environment which I run it:

```
source activate my_env
python my_server.py
```

I would like to convert it to as `systemd` service, so I created my_server.service file:

```
[Service]
User=myuser
Group=myuser
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/myuser/.conda/envs/my_env/bin/python /path/to/my_server.py
```

This does not work because the `systemd` is being run as the root user and I can not activate the `conda` environment to get the all path right.
What is the correct way to create a `systemd` service when the executable requires a specific `conda` env to run?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can run systemd services on user level instead of running on system level, which will run it as root user. Instead of putting the .service file on /etc/systemd/system directory, you have put the file inside ~/.config/systemd/user/ directory and no need of `User` and `Group` derivative. For example:

```
[Unit]
Description=Description
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/
ExecStart=/home/myuser/.conda/envs/my_env/bin/python my_server.py

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Instead of starting this service with privileged permission, you can start with the running user permission using `systemctl --user start/restart/stop servicename` command. No need of sudo privilege or password.

Comment: If I run it as a user, can I configure it to run at every boot automatically?

Comment: Yes you can, for system level services `WantedBy=multiuser.target` is required for a system to be enabled, in case of user level services, `WantedBy=default.target`. For starting at boot, you have to enable-linger for that user, command is `loginctl enable-linger username`. You can just enable the service using `systemctl --user enable servicename` command.

Comment: It looks like this solution wouldn't actually activate the conda environment – which will be problematic if `my_server.py` depends on conda packages with activation scripts.