# how do I make systemd service to run python project with conda env through .sh

Tags: python, linux, bash, daemon

I'm trying to run my code on startup through systemd
I want it to run using the current environment cause it's a bit big and I don't want to reinstall all of that

I have a .sh file that activates the python environment and calls the starting script on a big project
I then made a service that calls that sh

```
[Unit]
Description=service to start code 

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/usr/bin
ExecStart=/home/administrator/Downloads/open_app/out_cam_app.sh



[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

#https://transang.me/three-ways-to-create-a-startup-script-in-ubuntu/
```

but this fives these errors

```
22 18:17:56 smart-fk systemd[1]: Started service to start 
22 18:17:56 smart-fk my_bas_Script.sh[1417930]: /path/to/my_bas_Script.sh: line 3: /root/anaconda3/bin/activa>
22 18:17:56 smart-fk out_cam_app.sh[1417931]: /path/to/my_bas_Script.sh: line 6: python: command not found
22 18:17:56 smart-fk out_cam_app.sh[1417932]: /path/to/my_bas_Script.sh: line 7: conda: command not found
22 18:17:56 smart-fk systemd[1]: my_Service.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
22 18:17:56 smart-fk systemd[1]: my_Service.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

my bash script looks like this in case it's the problem (it works on its own tho)

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate env_name 
cd path/to/python/project
python python_start_point.py
conda deactivate
```

I also tried making the service call the code directly and that made the code work [stackover flow post that I used for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928299/how-to-convert-a-python-script-in-a-local-conda-env-into-systemd-service-in-linu)then start downloading some files , which I can't do on this machine
so it failed cause of the connection time out

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I really try to use this community the right way, but this harsh community votes me down instead of telling me how to fix it whenever I do something they believe is remotely wrong. do you really think the whole question is invalid because of a tag that needs to be fixed ?

Comment: The tag is not what makes your question off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `WorkingDirectory=/usr/bin` and add the executable path to:

`Environment="PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"`